# Error printing image with Raspberry Pi and OpenCV face detection (imshow function)

Tags: python, opencv, raspberry-pi

I'm trying to build a simple surveillance program with the Raspberry Pi Camera, using OpenCV for face detection. This is my code:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*- 
from picamera.array import PiRGBArray
from picamera import PiCamera
import time
import cv2

#setting up the camera 
camera = PiCamera()
camera.resolution = (320, 240)
camera.framerate = 30
rawCapture = PiRGBArray(camera, size=(320, 240))

#basic cascade classifier
face_cascade = cv2.CascadeClassifier('haarcascade_frontalface_default.xml')
#0.1 sec warmup 
time.sleep(0.1)

# capture frames from the camera
for frame in camera.capture_continuous(rawCapture, format="bgr", use_video_port=True):  
    image = frame.array
    gray = cv2.cvtColor(image, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
    faces = face_cascade.detectMultiScale(gray, 1.3, 5)

    #rectangle  loop
    for(x, y, w, h) in faces:
        image = cv2.rectangle(image,(x, y), (x+w, y+h), (255, 0, 0), 2)

    # show the frame [here comes the problem]
    cv2.imshow("Frame", image)
    #   cv2.imshow("Gray", gray
    key = cv2.waitKey(100) & 0xFF

# clear the stream in preparation for the next frame
rawCapture.truncate(0)
# if the `q` key was pressed, break from the loop
if key == ord("q"):
    break
```

The point is that, when I draw the rectangle in the image, it comes up with this error:

> OpenCV Error: Assertion failed (size.width>0 && size.height>0) in
>   imshow, file /home/pi/opencv-2.4.10/modules/highgui/src/window.cpp,
>   line 261 Traceback (most recent call last):   File "camera2.py", line
>   36, in 
>       cv2.imshow("Frame", image) cv2.error: /home/pi/opencv-2.4.10/modules/highgui/src/window.cpp:261: error:
>   (-215) size.width>0 && size.height>0 in function imshow

If I put the cv2.imshow right before the rectangle loop, it works perfectly. Also, printing the *faces* object shows that the *detectMultiScale* is actually recognizing the faces. What should I do?

Thanks.

Comment: are you using opencv3.0 or 2.4 ? cv2.rectangle() does **not** return an image in 2.4, thus you overwrite it with 'None' , and then imshow() complains about that.

Comment: just try to skip the `image =` part.

Comment: That just worked for me. THANKS :)

Comment: yea, known pitfall. the opencv tutrorials are nice, but written with opencv3.0 in mind.